# How to inform my application (producer) that it is blocked by ActiveMQ server?

Tags: spring-integration, activemq-artemis

I am using Artemis ActiveMQ for internal asynchronous processes of my application. 

All the connection logic is handled by Spring Integration. 

I've encountered a low disk space scenario on the artemis server. This resulted in artmeis server blocking my message producers, without any warning (except a warning in the artemis server log). However it can be any other blocking scenario.
The application continued to produce messages, without being aware that the messages aren't written to the queue.
How can my application (producer) be informed about such an infrastructure issue, so I can throw exception or log an error, that will be visible at my applications' end.

Answer (score 0):

If your application sends messages asynchronously then there's no way for it to know about problems sending the message (except for problems that happen specifically on the client). Sending messages async is "fire-and-forget"; the client just sends them and doesn't really care about what happens to them. You'd need to send them *synchronously* in order to get any indication of a problem on the broker.

Answer (score 0):

Like ActiveMQ the Artemis server supports [producer flow control](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.4.0/flow-control.html) (personally never used it). While the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html) explicitly states that it also applies to async producers provided you set the Producer Window Size on the connection factory the Artemis documentation says nothing about it. But the windowing concept is the same. You probably should give it a shot.